# Convert date to day-of-week in R

Tags: r, date

I have a date in this format in my data frame:

```
"02-July-2015"
```

And I need to convert it to the day of the week (i.e. 183). Something like:

```
df$day_of_week <- weekdays(as.Date(df$date_column))
```

But this doesn't understand the format of the dates.

Comment: Is that July 2nd? What year? That date will fall on a different weekdays in different years.

Comment: Yes sorry, it is July 2nd, 2015

Comment: The documentation for `as.Date` specifies a `format` argument: `as.Date("02-July-2015",format = "%d-%B-%Y")`.

Comment: The format argument to the as.Date function, not to weekday. Also I think the as.Date function only accepts then months abbreviations. July -> Jul

Comment: I see. Got it thank you. This gives the day, not the number, but that's an easy conversion

Comment: `unclass(as.POSIXlt(as.Date("02-July-2015", "%d-%B-%Y")))$yday + 1`

Comment: Another option would be `strftime(as.Date("02-Jan-2015",format = "%d-%b-%Y"), format = "%j")`

Comment: You can also use `lubridate` to do this and do something like the following `wday(dmy("02-July-2015"))`.  The call to `lubridate::wday` will return the day number but has options to change to day name.  For day of year you would do the following `yday(dmy("02-July-2015"))`

Comment: @Cybernetic Your question asks for day of week but uses the day of year as an example, you may want to edit the question to clarify (even if both are desired).

Answer (score 8):

You could use `lubridate` to convert to day of week or day of year.

```
library(lubridate)

# "02-July-2015" is Thursday
date_string <- "02-July-2015"
dt <- dmy(date_string)
dt
## [1] "2015-07-02 UTC"

### Day of week : (1-7, Sunday is 1)
wday(dt)
## [1] 5

### Day of year (1-366; for 2015, only 365) 
yday(dt)
## [1] 183

### Or a little shorter to do the same thing for Day of year
yday(dmy("02-July-2015"))
## [1] 183
```

Answer (score 3):

```
day = as.POSIXct("02-July-2015",format="%d-%b-%Y")

# see ?strptime for more information on date-time conversions

# Day of year as decimal number (001–366).
format(day,format="%j")
[1] "183"

#Weekday as a decimal number (1–7, Monday is 1).
format(day,format="%u")    
[1] "4"
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what [anotherFishGuy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36774943/6549166) supposed, plus converting the values to `as.numeric` so they fit through classifier.

```
# day <- Sys.time()
as.num.format <- function(day, ...){
   as.numeric(format(day, ...))
}
doy <- as.num.format(day,format="%j")
doy <- as.num.format(day,format="%u")
hour <- as.num.format(day, "%H")
```