# Date to weekday (internationalization) prefer returning numbers

Tags: r

How can I convert the date into weekday in numeric form?
Similar question here:[Find the day of a week](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9216138/find-the-day-of-a-week-in-r)

When run on my computer, the out put look like this:

```
> weekdays.Date(as.Date("2016-12-31"))
[1] "星期六"
```

But I am designing a program that will be dispatched to people from all over the world.

Same code run on different computer might give different result:

```
> weekdays.Date(as.Date("2016-12-31"))
[1] "Saturday"
```

This makes the situation complicated if I need to consider putting a translation chunk in my code.

I wonder if there is a way that, when doing the conversion it returns weekdays in numbers. For instance, Monday is 1, Tuesday is 2 ..., Sunday is 7.

Comment: A similar question had been answered before:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/36774943/5911315

Answer (score 0):

From `strptime` help...

`format(as.Date("2017-03-12"),"%u")`